# How to enable generic types <T> on android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm programing in kotlin and I have tried using Hashmap however it gives me this eror:Unresolved reference, I've tried importing java.lang.reflect.*; but it's not helping.

here is my code (The IDE does not recognize T):

```
    fun updateValues(map:HashMap<String,T>){
            map.keys.forEach { key->{
                when(map[key]){
                    is String-> sharedPrefrences.edit().putString(key,map[key])
                    is Integer-> sharedPrefrences.edit().putInt(key,map[key])
                }
            } }
            sharedPrefrences.edit().apply()
        }
```

Comment: Please post a relevant bit of your code and the specific error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the type parameter for your function, e.g.

```
fun <T> updateValues(map:HashMap<String,T>){ ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If `T` is only needed in that function, then you need to have a properly declared *Generic function*: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generic-functions

```
fun <T> updateValues(map: HashMap<String,T>)
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use generics here, because SharedPreferences still won't be able to cast the value in your when block.

Here a solution without explicit casts or generics:

```
fun updateValues(map:HashMap<String,*>) {
    map.keys.forEach { key ->
        with(map[key]) {
            when (this) {
                is String -> sharedPrefrences.edit().putString(key, this)
                is Int -> sharedPrefrences.edit().putInt(key, this)
            }
        }
    }
    sharedPrefrences.edit().apply()
}
```